# How can i add data column wise in materialui table in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can i add data column wise in materialui table in reactjs. For example I have 100 branches for my business, i want the table header with branch name and that column should contain names of the employees.
So there should be 100 table header.
Array=[{branchname: 'String', employees[]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, ok you have to work a little bit with your data structure because Materual UI `Table` accepts data organized per rows and not per columns as you need.

Lets say you have your data like:

```
const branchEmployees = [
  { branchname: "branch1", employees: ["e1", "e2", "e3"] },
  { branchname: "branch2", employees: ["e4", "e5", "e6"] },
  { branchname: "branch3", employees: ["e7", "e8", "e9"] },
  { branchname: "branch4", employees: ["e10", "e11", "e12"] },
  { branchname: "branch5", employees: ["e13", "e14", "e15"] }
];
```

So at first create an array with all branches name. Something like:

```
let bEmp = [];
branchEmployees.forEach((el) => {
   bEmp.push(el.branchname);
});
```

Then we have to revert the employees data in this way:

From:

```
   employees: ["e1", "e2", "e3"]
   employees: ["e4", "e5", "e6"]
   employees: ["e7", "e8", "e9"]
   employees: ["e10", "e11", "e12"]
   employees: ["e13", "e14", "e15"]
```

To:

```
   employees: ["e1", "e4", "e7", "e10", "e13"]
   employees: ["e2", "e5", "e8", "e11", "e14"]
   employees: ["e3", "e6", "e9", "e12", "e15"]
```

To achieve this, you could define a const that represent the max number of employees per branch and then make a nested `for loop` to make the above transformation. Something like:

```
const NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES_PER_BRANCH = 3; // this is the max number of employees per branch
let arrLp = [];
for (let j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES_PER_BRANCH; j++) {
   let arrayLookup = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < branchEmployees.length; i++) {
      arrayLookup.push(branchEmployees[i].employees[j]);
   }
   arrLp.push(arrayLookup);
}
```

So now you have `bEmp` that contains all the branches name and `arrLp` that contains all the employees per line.

Now it's just necessary to create 2 state variables to store these values and use them on `Table` component.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-forked-iiv3g?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example.

Note: this solution works also if you have different number of employees per branch. It's just necessary to set `NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES_PER_BRANCH` to the maximum number of employees that a branch could have :)